# Is there way to check that two drives or folders have the same files but in different folder structure in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, mirroring

I have a situation where I am copying thousands of photos of different filetypes into new folders on a new drive. Photos in their current state are unorganized and need to be structured better. I will copy the picturefiles manualy. My concern is that after I am done I might miss some pictures in my newly organised drive. I cannot simply compare the two drives (or folders) because their subfolders are not mirrors of themselves.

Essentialy I want to tell my computer:
"Check that every individual file (not checking folders) in `F:\oldpictures` has excact copy in somewhere in `D:\newpictures`. If file (picture) is missing notify user."

What would be the easiest way to check this? Is there a way built into windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

I have used the [Funduc](https://www.funduc.com/)  "Duplicate file finder" in the past for this purpose ***SPECIFICALLY*** in addition to using for hunting duplicate mp3s.  It uses MD5 checksums to determine if the files are the same so it doesn't even matter if they have the same name or not or what path they might be in.

You can find it  [here](https://www.funduc.com/dupfiles.htm).

Good luck.

Also.. shout out to this free funduc tool! .. I myself have been paying for [Search And Replace](https://www.funduc.com/search_replace.htm)  for years.  Nothing searches text or binary nearly as well.  They need to pay the bills somehow.

Comment: I read the documentation and it seems promising. I hope I have time to finish it within 24 hours, and I will report back.

Comment: I could not get it to work in a usefull manner. I found duplicate files, but could not find the files that have no duplicate. I think it still might be possible though, because the documentation states: "you can use Duplicate File Finder to scan just those two paths, with the expectation that you should see two of each file once the scan is complete". Maybe masks or filters?

In my case I checked there are over 12.000 files that all should have a duplicate. This is quite impossible if I can't see if the individual files are missing. Even so that would be tedious job with that many photos.